# Hash с повторяющимися элементами

Tags: json, ruby, хеширование

Как на Ruby записать в хеш одинаковые элементы?

Comment: @PashaPash сделано

Answer (score 5):

Элементы с одинаковыми ключами - никак.

`{ a: 'b', a: 'c' }` - вернет хэш `{ a: 'c' }`.

Хэш содинаковыми значениями для разных ключей - можно: `{ b: 'a', c: 'a' }`.

Если нужно под одним ключом хранить несколько разных элементов, то их нужно упаковать в массив: `{ a: ['b', 'c'] }`